# How to add a unit to the end of <input type="number"> properly in HTML(5)?

Tags: html, forms, html-input

I would like to have an `<input type="number">` that has a unit at the end (m<sup>2</sup>), but the user can't change it. I have this for now:

```
<label>
  Area:
  <input type="number" name="area">
</label>
```

I guess I can't just add a unit directly after the `<input>` because that would probably mess up the `<label>`. So what do I do? Would it be best to separate the `<label>` using the `for` attribute or add an `::after` pseudo-element using CSS or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you could use the ::after pseudoselector, the best approach is to use the m2 in the label to give more contextual information to the value that is expected int the input. In other words - the label informs the user as to what the value means in the input.

Note the `<sup>` element that allows the superscript rendering of the 2.

```html
<label>
  Area (m<sup>2</sup>):
  <input type="number" name="area">
</label>
```

You could also create a span with the content and include it within the label -after the input and it would show at the end of the input.

```html
<label>
  Area:
  <input type="number" name="area">
  <span> m<sup>2</sup></span>
</label>
```

You could even position it absolutely so it shows in the input field itself - but given that this is a number type of input - browsers will insert a 'stepper at the extreme right of the field - so you would need to wither move it to the left to avoid that, or  use a type="text" input and validate the input to be numeric.

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

label span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Area:
  <input type="number" name="area">
  <span> m<sup>2</sup></span>
</label>
```